# What clock source is the oscillator connected at the OSC1 and OSC2 pins of a pic?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator, microchip

I'm connecting a Crystal SMD of 32 MHz to the `OSC1` and `OSC2` pins of a pic.

[image]

When doing the configurations for the pic, inside `System Module` on `clock source` i have there some options, including `primary oscillator`, `external oscillator`, and others.

[image]

I've read in some place that it is a Primary oscillator, but the logic on my mind says that it's external, which is right?

The pic in cause is `PIC32MX470F512LT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I've read in some place that it is a Primary oscillator, but the logic on my mind says that it's external, which is right?*

An **external** clock or oscillator is a (usually square wave) signal which is generated by some other circuit.

Your setup is a **Primary oscillator** as the clock is generated locally by the combination of the PIC uC and the crystal.

So choose: Primary oscillator.

Comment: Thank you, most of sources i've read point to that. Thanks for clarification.